# Python/Pycharm access and permissions problem, I can't move file to another direction using os.replace()

Tags: python, pycharm, operating-system, file-permissions, access-denied

I tried this code:

```
import os

src = "C:\\Users\\grzyb\\Desktop\\Python\\test.txt"
dst = "C:\\Users\\grzyb\\Desktop\\Python\\eoeoeoe"

try:
    os.replace(src, dst)
    print(src+" was moved")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(src+" was not found")
```

But I get an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Python\learning\main.py", line 365, in <module>
    os.replace(src, dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Python\\learning\\test.txt' -> 'C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\Python\\learning\\eoeoeoe'
```

Even if I run PyCharm as an administrator I still have the same permission error. What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Even as an administrator, you will generally not be allowed to overwrite the `dst` unless the program runs as the **owner** of that file. This is a standard thing about how file permissions work, and is really a question about the operating system, not about the code.